# @JsonIgnore Behaviour

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

While working on a project, I made the mistake of putting a @JsonIgnore on the setter rather than the getter property as below

```
private Set<Book> books;  


public Set<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}
```

This should have resulted in my getbooks api call working fine (calling from postman). 
However, i realise that @JsonIgnore prevents serialisation even if the @JsonIgnore is set on the setter.

Is this how normally @JsonIgnore works ? I thought setting @JsonIgnore only on the getter prevents serialisation. Here it is preventing serialisation even if i put it on the getter or the setter.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you referred this [post](http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/10/jackson-json-difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonignoreproperties-annotations/) on `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Thanks Ranjith. I happened to read that just before posting, but the message was nuanced and it probably didn't register in my thick skull. Re-reading that after RC's response below makes it all very clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) (emphasis is mine):

> In addition, starting with Jackson 1.9, if this is the only annotation associated with a property, it will also cause cause the whole property to be ignored: **that is, if setter has this annotation and getter has no annotations, getter is also effectively ignored**. It is still possible for different accessors to use different annotations; so if only "getter" is to be ignored, other accessors (setter or field) would need explicit annotation to prevent ignoral (usually `JsonProperty`).